# how to fix unique constraint in OnetoOneField in migrate step

Tags: python, django

I am not getting why the unique constraint is failed every time.     #models.py

```
from django.db import models
# Create your models here.

class usersclass(models.Model):    
    user =  models.OneToOneField(
        'auth.User',
        default = False,
        on_delete = models.CASCADE,
        related_name = 'profiles',
    )


I am using Meta class for including Fields

#forms.py

from django import forms
from .models import usersclass
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class usersclassForm(forms.ModelForm):
    """Form definition for userclass."""
    class Meta:
        """Meta definition for userclassform."""
        model = usersclass
        fields = ('name_full','address','Gender','timestamp','Mobile_num','landline_number')
```

Authentication is done properly but i am unable to migrate my models
    #veiws.py

```
    def post(self,request,*args,**kwargs):
        form = LoginForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = authenticate(
                username = form.cleaned_data['Name'],
                password = form.cleaned_data['password'],
            )
            if user is not None:
                login(request,user)
                return HttpResponse()
```

Comment: why you set a boolean as default value for OnetoOnefield?

Comment: Because i was trying to login user who is already registered, Any new user has to signup and be able to login

Comment: can you provide the error message when you try to migrate?

Answer (score 0):

Don't do `default=False` and give `unique=True` then run makemigrations and migrate to add unique constraint.

Comment: it is not working same problem, login_usersclass.user_id  - UNIQUE constraint failed